# rsyslog + PgSql + RegExp

Tags: регулярные-выражения, rsyslog

В syslog прибегают такие логи (только такого формата) -

```
v.zagorodnih logged in, 192.168.101.128 from 100.100.200.200
v.zagorodnih logged out, 27385 368972558 4507166275 4078118 5076137 from 100.100.200.200
```

Я пытался разобрать эту запись шаблоном

```
template (name="tpl" type="string" option.stdsql="on" string="insert into vpn (datestamp,message,fromhost,login)
values ('%timegenerated:0:19:date-rfc3339%','%msg%','%hostname%','%msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:^.(\\S+)\\s+--end%')")
```

да, логин (v.zagorodnih) у меня получилось выдернуть но я понимаю что мой путь не верный.
Вопрос - как мне разобрать такие строчки (msg) что бы каждое слово попала в свое поле БД
и тут же вытекающий вопрос - как это сделать с учетом что в logged in и logged out разное количество полей. Спасибо